# IoT sensor data format unification

Tags: format, iot, sensors

In an IoT system, as there are many sources of sensor data, formats are supposed to be different. While accumulating them in the DB it should conform to the standard (some fixed format, say JSON etc.).
Is it possible to build such application/interface so that it can accept more than one type of data-input? I mean some kind of 'converter' mechanism to change the incoming sensor data format to the pre-decided format?

Any related links/documents would also be very helpful.

Thanks and regards

Answer (score 1):

If you use EMQ X MQTT broker, it comes with a 'rule engine' that supports an SQL query language to transform data.
The current stable release 4.3 comes with some builtin string functions which are documented here: https://docs.emqx.io/en/broker/v4.3/rule/rule-engine.html#string-functions
However, it requires the payload to be text-based.
In the 5.0 release (not GA yet), there will be support for any binary data transformation.

Comment: Thank you very much for the replay and the link.

Comment: Very happy if I can offer some help~